# How to debug a MVC5 Library deployed via IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

i have a MVC5 project using .NET Framework 4.7.2
it is build as a library - so no exe file. and it is deployed via IIS.

so usually this stuff just works - though i don't know how. but now i want to migrate to a new csproj pattern, which modern applications use. all to get rid of the manual import of every single project file, i think you know how it goes.

the problem is whenever i try to debug it as IIS it just fails, because it can't run a DLL file. it's just not configured...

the build is OK, everything else was migrated just fine. i'm not even switching the target framework, all i want is a cleaner csproj format. so please help me because i tried now for hours and google is not really helpful

as requested:
the new csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"  />


    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
        <ProjectGuid>{881DFF8A-F36B-4948-A62E-9E3A9BD6D9C9}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
        <WcfConfigValidationEnabled>True</WcfConfigValidationEnabled>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
        <IISExpressSSLPort>443</IISExpressSSLPort>
        <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
        <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
        <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
        <TargetFrameworkProfile />
        <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
        <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
        <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
        <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
      <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
      <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
      <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
      <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
      <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" Version="4.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Web" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    {PROJECT REFERENCES CENSORED}
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
        <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"  />

    <ProjectExtensions>
        <VisualStudio>
            <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
                <WebProjectProperties>
                    <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
                    <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
                    <DevelopmentServerPort>51599</DevelopmentServerPort>
                    <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
                    <IISUrl>http://localhost/Server</IISUrl>
                    <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
                    <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
                    <CustomServerUrl>
                    </CustomServerUrl>
                    <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
                </WebProjectProperties>
            </FlavorProperties>
        </VisualStudio>
    </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

the old csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{881DFF8A-F36B-4948-A62E-9E3A9BD6D9C9}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <WcfConfigValidationEnabled>True</WcfConfigValidationEnabled>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort>443</IISExpressSSLPort>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\NLog.4.1.0\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Serilog.2.9.0\lib\net46\Serilog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Serilog.Sinks.File.4.1.0\lib\net45\Serilog.Sinks.File.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.IO.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.0\lib\net463\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Cors, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Cors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.Cors, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.Cors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
 { TONS OF CONTENT INCLUDE PER FILE IN SOLUTION }
  <ItemGroup>
  { PROJECT REFERENCES CENSORED }
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>51599</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost/Server</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

i tried to put everything from old to new... i also tried using different project sdks like the normal .NET Sdk and the Sdk.Web

Comment: you need some application which calls this dll, otherwise you cant run a dll directly

Comment: and this application should be the IIS.
Usually when debugging the IIS the debugger attaches to the IIS process w3w.exe or so, associated to the application pool and then debugging is possible
and it was possible when this app used the old csproj pattern (if neccessary i could post old vs. new csproj format)
but i don't know how to configure this now.
because our project has no entry point, it has a global.asax

Comment: then you should provide the complete info on how are you debugging and what changes have you made

Comment: no secret for debugging i just click on the play-button^^

Comment: .NET Framework projects should stay in the old project format. Period. All attempt to use the SDK style project format is just a waste of time.

Comment: i see... well i would hope that someone still knew a solution for this one... i mean there must be one, visual studio is capable there is just some syntax to be implemented... and i don't know it >.< 

in the worst case i keep the old project format and use Foder include with wildcards but... bah!

it'd take years to migrate our stuff to .NET Core and if we don#t change something we have every hour a new merge conflict because someone changes some files, adds a file, removes a file or edits the csproj

Comment: Why do you need to debug it on iis deployment? You can do it directly in vs: [How to: Debug from a DLL project in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-from-a-dll-project?view=vs-2019).

Comment: because it is an iis backend service^^ so i need to run request against it

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: You may create virtual directory from visual studio and u should be able to debug

Comment: @ZahidMustafa can you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to manually attach the debugger to the IIS process?  We work in a similar fashion (library that is hosted in IIS, using new CSProj style for all the projects), but I never use the "play" button to debug.  The app gets built, we set the "Physical Path" value in the "Basic settings" of the site in IIS to the folder for the project, hit the site, and then within Visual Studio under the Debug menu select "Attach to Process...":

[image: Attach to process]

Then select "w3wp.exe" (You might have to check "Show processes from all users" first and click "Attach".  Then, your breakpoints should be hit.  Note that you will need to be running Visual Studio as administrator in order to attached to the w3wp process though.

Comment: this would be possible but i fear people will not accept my PR if it makes debugging more complex - even just by little
because before the migration we could use the play button. and now all the people need to get used to attach to process :S 

but still thank you very much for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all you need to create AppPool and WebSite in IIS.
Set WebSite folder to your web project (folder where web.config is placed, NOT bin folder).

Then you can debug with 2 options:

1. Press "Play" button than Visual Studio opens browser and you can debug Frontend+Backend.
2. Just build your project and press in menu Debug->Attach to process->Choose "w3wp.exe". with this option you can debug just Backend part.

Comment: the point of this question is that i cannot press "play button". but i need to press this play button :( 
the point is after switching to the SDK csproj pattern the play button is not working anymore. 
i mean you can also reproduce that quite easy. create a WCF Web Application project, edit the CSPROJ and change the some lines to the <project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> ... </project> pattern. you could also try to remove the .Web to have normal console application but still. debugging with play button does no longer work :(

Comment: Are you uses Microsoft Upgrade Assistant?
https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant
Or you make all by hands?

Comment: i do it by hand... our project is nothing that any assistant could migrate

Comment: So, this assistant migrate only project type (do not change sources). Please try it to migrate and compare results. May be some parameters not applied and all works incorrect. Most of your projects migrates correct (or need only some changes by hands)

Comment: [15:25:45 ERR] Support for Web Forms is limited to .NET Full Framework. To learn more please read: https://aka.ms/migrate-web-forms
[15:25:45 ERR] Support for WCF Server-side Services is limited to .NET Full Framework. To learn more please read: https://aka.ms/migrate-wcf-to-grpc
[15:25:45 ERR] Project D:\AHP One\AhpWCFServices\ahpFrontendWCFService\ahpFrontendWCFService.csproj uses feature(s) that are not supported.

Comment: so in general, i tried the migration tool and the whole application basically dies... also i don't see any difference in the resulted csproj.
a .NET 5 port for our project will not be possible. and the csproj is now changed to the SDK pattern but a lot of stuff is broken and the IIS is still not working ^^